# Matrix equation XAX=B where the solution must be diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$X_{solution}=\arg\min_X \|XAX-B|_F \quad\mathrm{subject\ to}$$

X is square and diagonal

A is square and positive semi-definite

B is square and positive semi-definite

Any pointers or relevant search terms?

Comment: Perhaps you could add detail about the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert, we can assume that $A$ is diagonal and $X$ is symmetric, that I shall do in the sequel. We suppose that the matrices are real. You seek the argmin of the function $f:X\in Sym\rightarrow trace(UU^T)$ where $U=XAX-B$. Then $D_Xf=0$ iff, for every symmetric matrix $H$, 
$trace((AX^2AX+XAX^2A-AXB-BXA)H)=0$. Therefore,
any symmetric candidate $X$ satisfies $AX^2AX+XAX^2A-AXB-BXA=0$ (system of equations of degree $3$), that is equivalent to $AX(XAX-B)$ is skew symmetric.

EDIT: Federico, you are right, but, in my mind, the OP assumed $X$ diagonal in order to simplify the problem. Yet, if $X$ is a unknown symmetric matrix, then we cannot assume that it is diagonal. Of course, if the OP correctly stated his question, then I considered a distinct problem.

Now we assume that $X=diag((x_i)_i)$. Let $Z=AX^2AX+XAX^2A-AXB-BXA$. In the same way, we obtain: for every $H$ diagonal,  $trace(ZH)=0$. Therefore, for every $i$, $Z_{i,i}=0$ and we have a system of $n$ equations of degree $3$ in the $n$ unknowns $(x_i)_i$. More precisely, if $A=[a_{i,j}],B=[b_{i,j}]$, then for every $i$, $\sum_j a_{i,j}^2x_i{x_j}^2-\sum_ja_{i,j}b_{i,j}x_j=0$.

Comment: I don't think that this works. When you make the change of variable that diagonalizes $A$, $X$ does not vary in the whole set of symmetric matrices, but in a smaller variety of dimension $n$. So you can't simply set $D_X f=0$; it's a constrained minimum problem that does not look simpler than the original one.

Comment: If $X$ is generic, then $XAX=B$ has a closed form solution (assuming invertibility). So the key point seems to be the diagonal nature, which I think can be handled without too much trouble)

Comment: @Suvrit, you write too quickly. Firstly, $X$ depends on $A,B$ ; in particular, if $A$ is invertible and $B$ is not, a solution $X$ of $XAX=B$ is certainly not generic. Secondly, if $A,B$ are generic in the PDS set, then $XAX=B$ has $2^n$ symmetric solutions and no diagonal solutions. Thirdly: read my edit.

Comment: If $A > 0$ and $B \ge 0$, then $XAX=B$ has a positive definite solution given by $X=A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$, that's all I meant when I wrote my comment --- this is the only positive definite solution to this Riccati equation, and given the optimization formulation, any solution is acceptable, so might as well take the positive one!

Comment: Yes Suvrit, I agree. If $X$ is only assumed to be symmetric and $A,B$ are generic, then the minimum is $0$. That shows the interest to assume that $X$ is a diagonal matrix. Yet, I do not know if this hypothesis on $X$ is associated to (only) a mathematical exercise or to a practical use of Riccati equations.